Bitnami MEAN stack won't start after port change
UUPDATE 2: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html#bus-names the only official document on the data packet/marshalling of dbus. It is very short of examples and never dumps an entire packet. There are dbus-scrape,dbus-spy programs on github.com supposedly]
[UPDATE:I reverted back to port 80 and got the same thing.
I then installed strace and the last references are to socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM)
connect('/run/systemd/private')
recvmesg (\7\1s\0\30\0\0\0/org.freedesktop.systemd1....)
]
I installed bitnami meanstack 7.0-7.0.14-r1-debian-12-amd64 on VirtualBox on a ubuntu (kernel 6.5.0-44).
I changed the http port to 7xxx.
/opt/bitnami/ctlscript restart apache fails with a message in red saying 'control process exited with error code'. There are also references to 'journalctl -xeu'
that reveals nothing.
/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/apachectl -D LogLevel=debug  -S -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf reports:

VirtualHost Configuration;
127.0.0.1:7xxx.  status.localhost (/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/00_status-vhost.conf:1)
*:7XXX  192.168.x.y (/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami.conf:6)
*:443.  192.168.x.y (/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf:15)

I tried LogLevel=emerg but nothing new. It still onto start.
ss shows nothing.'netstat' is not available. The conventional error_log file only shows a single line about receiving a SIGTERM.  *nft has been updated. The 'apachectl configtest' says 'Syntax OK'.
ThankX in advance.
