apach2.4 fail on bitnami VS d-bus
[UPDATE: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html#bus-names the only official document on the data packet/marshalling of dbus. It is very short of examples and never dumps an entire packet. There are dbus-scrape,dbus-spy programs on github.com supposedly]
I am trying strace to analyze apache2.4's startup failure on a bitnami VirtualBox image.[[https://serverfault.com/questions/1165950/bitnami-mean-stack-wont-start-after-port-change]]
But I am unable to interpret the d-bus exchange aside from a login using supposedly not on by default fd's and reading in the last exchange about the property org.freedesktop.systemd.Unit1.
NOTE: Installing python pydbus and dbus_next still will not allow me to use the Array. Why is this?
The final dbus message is:
Strace says: "1\2\1\1\22\0\0\0\26\0\0\0007\0\0\0\5\1u\0\4\0\0\0"
"\7\1s\0\30\0\0\0org.freedesktop.systemd1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\1g\0\1v\0\0\1s\0\0\t\0\0\0exit-code\0"
